# Create project laravel with composer [ERROR]

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am trying to create a new project with composer laravel, but I get this error, as could fix it ??

Note: I installed the .exe installer composer

[image: CMD]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a parameter your global `composer.json` file. On UNIX it's located in `~/.composer/composer.json` .

Open up that file and add this:
`"secure-http": false`

My whole `composer.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^1.3"
    },
    "secure-http": false
}
```

Since you're using Windows, you'll need to find where this file is.